# Is it possible create instance of derived type from instance of base class

Tags: python, metaclass

Some thing like this:

```
class Reference (object):
    pass
new_type = type ('{0}_refrence'.format (type (instance).__name__),
    (type (instance), Reference), {})
new_instance = new_type (instance)
```

I want to make instance to be derived from Refrence but behave as usual...
Is it possible?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want to do...

```
class Reference(object): pass

instance = 2
new_type = type('{0}_reference'.format(instance.__class__.__name__), (instance.__class__, Reference), {})
new_instance = new_type(instance)
```

Hope this helps.